# C function doesn't return after using __asm__ command

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, kernel, inline-assembly

I'm trying to build an operating system from scratch with a guide, https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial.
I've debugged the project I've made so far (chapter 16) and when I try to run it I encounter a problem in which I find the ip does not change back to the parent function after calling `void port_byte_out(unsigned short port, unsigned char data)`.

- ports.h - header file of the called function

```
unsigned char port_byte_in(unsigned short port);
void port_byte_out(unsigned short port, unsigned char data);
unsigned short port_word_in(unsigned short port);
void port_word_out(unsigned short port, unsigned short data);
```

- ports.c - code file of the called function

```
    unsigned char result;
    __asm__ ( " in %%dx , %%al " : "=a" ( result ) : "d" ( port ));
    return result ;
}

void port_byte_out ( unsigned short port , unsigned char data ) {
    __asm__ ( "out %%al , %%dx " : : "a" ( data ) , "d" ( port ));
}

unsigned short port_word_in ( unsigned short port ) {
    unsigned short result ;
    __asm__ ( " in %%dx , %%ax " : "=a" ( result ) : "d" ( port ));
    return result;
}

void port_word_out ( unsigned short port , unsigned short data ) {
    __asm__ ( " out %%ax , %%dx " : : "a" ( data ) , "d" ( port ));
}
```

- screen.c: `set_cursor_offset(int)` - code of the caller function

```
void set_cursor_offset(int offset) {
    offset /= 2;
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_CTRL, 14);
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_DATA, (unsigned char)(offset >> 8));
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_CTRL, 15);
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_DATA, (unsigned char)(offset & 0xff));
}
```

- makefile - may be unconventional use of things.. sorry, im new to using it :)

```
# $@ = target file
# $< = first dependcy
# $^ = all dependecies

C_SOURCES = $(wildcard kernel/*.c drivers/*.c)
HEADERS = $(wildcard kernel/*.h drivers/*.h)
OBJ = ${C_SOURCES:.c=.o}

CC = /usr/local/cross/bin/i686-elf-gcc
LD = /usr/local/cross/bin/i686-elf-ld
GDB = gdb

CFLAGS = -g

image.bin: boot_sector.bin kernel.bin
    cat $^ > $@

kernel.bin: boot/kernel_entry.o ${OBJ}
    ${LD} -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary

kernel.elf: boot/kernel_entry.o ${OBJ}
    ${LD} -g -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^

run: image.bin 
    qemu-system-x86_64 -fda $<

debug: image.bin kernel.elf
    qemu-system-x86_64 -s -fda image.bin &
    ${GDB} -ex "target remote localhost:1234" -ex "symbol-file kernel.elf"

%.o: */%.c ${HEADERS}
    ${CC} ${FLAGS} -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@

%.o: %.asm
    nasm $< -f elf -o $@

%.bin: */%.asm
    nasm $< -f bin -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.bin *.dis *.o *.elf
    rm kernel/*.bin kernel/*.o boot/*.bin boot/*.o
    rm drivers/*.bin drivers/*.o
    rm image.bin
```

- file tree -

```
.
├── bin
├── boot
│   ├── 32bit-gdt.asm     --> gdt table
│   ├── boot_sector.asm   --> boot sector
│   ├── disk_load.asm     --> read from disk function
│   ├── kernel_entry.asm  --> enter kernel - defines kernel_main
│   ├── print_32pm.asm    --> protected mode print(used before using the kernel functions)
│   ├── print.asm         --> real mode print
│   ├── print_hex.asm     --> real mode print hex nums
│   └── switch_32pm.asm   --> asm for switching to protected mode
├── drivers
│   ├── ports.c           --> talking to ports through the functions here
│   ├── ports.h           --> ports.c header file
│   ├── screen.c          --> screen memory writing, cursor and print functions
│   └── screen.h          --> screen.c header file
├── kernel
│   └── kernel_main.c     --> the kernel main
└── Makefile

4 directories, 14 files
```

Comment: That looks fine from a glance. How do you know ip does not change back? Is the function inlined or not? Use a debugger.

Comment: "when i try to run it" - How are you running it? You aren't just running this code as an executable under ubuntu, are you?

Comment: i use qemu and gdb debugger
followed the instructions and each time i get to port_byte_out the ip does not change after finishing and continues to the next function written in the address - port_word_in, and continues until it "reboots".. follow instructions until it gets to 0x7c00 and re-reads the boot sector

Comment: Can you show disassembly of `port_byte_out`, preferably with machine code? Since you mention `7c00`, is this a boot sector? Are you thus in real mode? Did you compile the code for 16 bit?

Comment: Compiled for 64 i868-elf-gcc. 0x7c00 as my boot sector starting point. Im pretty new to this stuff.. im in protected mode, the screen.c is a file from the kernel code

Comment: Use a debugger / simulator that tells you why it reboots, e.g. BOCHS with its built-in debugger should be good.  Does it triple fault?  Which asm instruction makes it reboot?  (Although even QEMU + GDB should be able to tell you that.)

Comment: i did debug it, i found out that instead of returning to the caller function it continues to execute instructions after the function port_byte_out

Comment: How does the disassembly look? Does it have a `ret`? What happens if you put a breakpoint there? What is on the stack?

Comment: I didnt succeed tracing the stack. The ret exists there. The thing that confuses me is that when there is not asm command there is no problem but when the asm command is different the problem persists.. it means by that, that the troublw maker must be the asm command but it makes no sense. Looked at ita description and found nothing about stack changing activity

Comment: Use the debugger. Put a breakpoint on the function. Single step until you hit the `ret`. Use `x/a $esp` or similar to examine stack. Verify value. Single step. Observe what happens. My guess is some sort of protection issue, possibly made worse by missing fault handler (but I did not check the sources). You still did not show disassembly. Also you can upload the image file somewhere for us to test.

Comment: https://github.com/thm4n/os-tempo-repo - current work branch of the project
added the disassembly there. i did observe the assembly file and it has a ret command. i do not know how to understand what i examine with the gdb x/a $esp, ui do understand it has the location in the stack followed by the value it holds but how do i test what is the correct value it should hold or what it saves as the return value when executing the -call- command. any answer appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i managed to find a solution that even though does not follow the conventional ways to code - it works..
i just used the code in the **asm** functions as is
inlined them manualy
why it didnt work before i do not know and have no clue and if someone has any possible idea i would like to understand a reasonable explanation.
thanks for anyone who tried to help!

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment. Please leave as commet if you donot answer the question.